# Are services also destroyed when the component providing them gets destroyed?

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose we have the following code:

```
@Component(
    // ..
    providers: [SomeService]
)
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(someService: SomeService) {}
}
```

Will the `someService` instance be destroyed whenever `SomeComponent` is destroyed? Or should one manually destroy it through `onDestroy()` hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they do, check out [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/P7yHPswDOaxD5MP7pGcf?p=preview)

You can check yourself with the ngOnDestroy hook in your service:

```
class SomeService{
  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('Service destroy')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45903985/3731501), providers follow the lifecycle and can have `OnDestroy` hook. They are destroyed when their injectors are destroyed.

If a provider belongs to component injector, it's destroyed with a component.

If a provider belongs to root injector, it's destroyed with an application.