# For the Angular router events Observable, why is there no unsubscribe()?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my **ngOnInit** method I am subscribing to the Router like this:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(
  event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) this.clearMessages();
  }
);
```

Normally, for **Observables** outside of the **HttpClient** package I call **unsubscribe** in the **ngOnDestroy** method but when I tried that here I discovered that **this.router.events** does not have such a method.  Am I mistaken or is there something different about this **Observable**?  Why would **unsubscribe** not be implemented?

Comment: If you console.log `router.events` you will see it is a Subject, so it has an unsubscribe method when you store the subscription. `let sub = this.router.events.subscribe()` if you console.log(sub) you will see it has the unsubscribe method.

Comment: @LLai the declaration for events is: **readonly events: Observable<Event>;** on line 159 in router.d.ts.  Are you sure that is right?

Comment: Yes he is right, because the result of `subscribe()` is what gets stored in `sub`.

Comment: It's fairly easy to see if you need to unsubscribe. Put a console.log in the above code and see if it keeps emitting after you navigate to another page.

Comment: @AlanObject yep. Eventhough it is readonly you can still subscribe to it. You just can't assign anything to it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I discovered that this.router.events does not have such a method

You call `unsubscribe` on subscriptions, not observables. And `this.router.events` is an observable, not subscription. So the following would work:

```
const subscription = this.router.events.subscribe(...);   
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Do this in ngOnDestroy() {..}

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi if we are subscribing router.evets in app.component.ts, then how can we unsubscribe() from app.component.ts? Because app.component.ts is main root component which never going to call ngOnDestroy() method throughout of application life-cycle. Is there any way to unsubscribe() router.evets from app.component.ts?

Answer (score 7):

You are right, some observables need no manual unsubscription from, observables like:

1. Router, HTTP, HTTPClient, because these are [single emission observables](https://www.seangwright.me/blog/development/unsubscribe-angular-2-http-observables/), although implicitly, and
2. Explicit single emission observables (e.g., finite), like `first()`

Similar information can be found on [this reddit site](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/66v9yy/so_we_should_never_really_unsubscribe_from/) also. This also means that no need to worry about memory leaks from observables in these classes.

**UPDATE**: please see comment below about Router.

Comment: I wouldn't say the observables from Router (Router + ActivatedRoute) are single emission observables. They can emit multiple times depending on if the events, params, queryParams, etc change. From this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/llai-router-cleanup?file=app%2Fcomponent-2%2Fcomponent-2.component.ts) it looks like ActivatedRoute observables clean up properly when the component is destroyed. However you can see `router.events` does not cleanup. I assume this is intentional since there are 3 navigation events after the component is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment and link. So, although `router.events` in particular don't clean up, is it safe to assume they won't cause memory leaks since they won't emit events when their parent component is destroyed? This of course can't be said about custom, infinitely emitting observables for example.

Comment: I believe you would run into the same issue. It will still emit events even if the parent component is destroyed. (Since there are navigation events after component destroy). I'm unsure of what are the use cases for router.events. If you use it say at the top level component of your app. It only gets subscribed to once so no need to clean it up since you will only have 1 subscribe running at a time. If you do however subscribe to it in multiple components then it looks like you will have to clean it up properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is work for me. Full example.

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  routerEventSubscription: Subscription;
  private destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routerEventSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // your code
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.routerEventSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.destroy$.next(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: you also need to call `this.destroy$.complete()` at the end of `ngOnDestroy`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232393/1438576