# ngOnDestroy not fired when service is provided using useFactory

Tags: angular

`HelloComponent` gets a `SampleService` instance, defining a Service Provider.
When `HelloCompoment` is destroyed, I don't understand why `SampleService` survives.

If `HelloComponent` got a `SampleService` instance by type (avoiding `ServiceProvider`), no problem occurs.

---

sample-service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService implements OnDestroy{

 constructor(){
   console.log('created new sample service');
 }

 ngOnDestroy(){
  console.log('destroyed sample service');
 }
}
```

---

hello-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core'
import { SampleService } from '../service/sample.service'

let ServiceFactory = () => {
  console.log('Providing new SampleService');
  return new SampleService();
};

let ServiceProvider = { 
    provide: SampleService,
    useFactory: ServiceFactory
  };

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
  providers: [ServiceProvider]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

constructor(private sampleService: SampleService){}

ngOnInit(){
  console.log("Hello component created!")
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  console.log("Hello component destroyed!")
 }
}
```

Here stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkhmma
(click on toggleHello and see console logs)

How could I force the service destroying when component ends?

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056446/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-a-service-in-angular-5

Comment: sorry, in your link I don't find nothing about destroying of a service created by a factory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14818) [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22240) in Angular, but one that is (unfortunately) by design.

The presence of an `OnDestroy` callback hook is checked at *compile time* and since your `ServiceProvider` is wrapping a Factory which creates a `SampleService`, the Angular compiler unfortunately has no idea that this hook even exists, so it will never be called.

Comment: Ok, all reported issues have been closed a year ago. I'm a little bit confused, I'm using latest stable ver (7.2.x).
BTW, my service subscribes to some $subjects (rxjs) and it starts polling that never stops. any workaround?

Comment: Yes because it is something that Angular have decided is **by design**. I presume they have no intentions of addressing it. I am not certain if there's any way around this I'm afraid, other than providing your service directly. You could also have your service only return an observable but **not** subscribe to it and then have the calling classes subscribe to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a service with `OnDestroy` to the service made by factory:

```
{
  provide: ServiceWithoutOnDestroy,
  useFactory: (..., unsubscribingService: UnsubscribingService) => new ServiceWithoutOnDestroy(..., unsubscribingService),
  deps: [..., UnsubscribingService],
}
```

**unsubscribing.service.ts**

```
/**
 * ## Usage
 *
 * <pre>
 *   @Component({
 *     ...,
 *     providers: [UnsubscribingService],
 *   })
 *
 *   ...
 *
 *   private destroyed$ = this.unsubscribingService.destroyed$;
 *
 *   ...
 *
 *   constructor(
 *     ...,
 *     private unsubscribingService: UnsubscribingService
 *   )
 *
 *   ...
 *
 *   source$.pipe(
 *     ...,
 *     takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
 *   )
 *
 *   ...
 * </pre>
 */
@Injectable()
export class UnsubscribingService implements OnDestroy {
  readonly destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```